# server rejected the request due to analyzer / generator issues 'analyzer assembly

Tags: docker

I am trying to build visual studio solution file in docker using msbuild command but getting below error:
Any idea on how to fix this?

````
 CompilerServer: server failed - server rejected the request due to analyzer / generator issues 'analyzer assembly 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\6.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\roslyn4.0\cs\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll' has MVID '1ab8574b-123c-4c58-ab19-0e17e8b5caf9' but loaded assembly 'System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration, Version=6.0.5.2210, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' has MVID 'efe30991-5b86-47af-9bf5-95750b60ed45'' - 90dd4855-cec1-409e-a5dc-283c53bd387c```
````